Using SOAP UI MockService with OnRequest script
I have created a MockService with two MockActions, each MockAction with two distinct MockResponses.
Based on the incoming Request content on the MockService (not on the MockAction), I want to dispatch the incoming request to the correct MockAction using the OnRequest Script of the MockRequest.
Practical use:

I receive a request in that MockService with the content "Reload Query"
In the OnRequest script I look into the incoming request for "Reload Query". If found, I then want to dispatch the request to the "Reload Query Mock" Mock Action.

This is the code I have been trying to use, and it's not working because the "context" variable is always null. I tried using the mockRunner.getMockContext() too, but it is also null.
How can I make this work?
SOAP UI MockService and Actions
// Get the current mock request body
def requestBody = mockRequest.getRequestContent()

// Retrieve the current mock operation from the context
def mockOperation = context.mockOperation

// Determine which response to set based on the content of the request body
switch (true) {
    case requestBody.contains("Generic Information Query"):
        // Set the response for the first action
        mockOperation.setResponse(mockOperation.getResponseByName("Generic Information Query")) // Assuming Generic Information Query is the name of the response for the first action
        break
    case requestBody.contains("Reloads Query"):
        // Set the response for the second action
        mockOperation.setResponse(mockOperation.getResponseByName("Reloads Query")) // Assuming Reloads Queryis the name of the response for the second action
        break
    default:
        context.responseStatus = 500
        context.responseHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'application/json' // Set the content type
        context.responseContent = '{"error": "Internal Server Error"}' // Set the error message in JSON format
}

